# jQuery - Toggle or Close an item when clicking in another on MENU

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, toggle

I'm creating a Menu with "ul" and "li", like this:
I want to create a Menu with all Titles closed, with an anchor to linked the page and a "+" after to open the subitems.

```
<a href="#">Main Lorem Ipsum</a> <span class="toggle-sub-menu" style="color: #ffff00;">+</span>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to make sure when I clicked in the ToggleIcon It closes the other ones open!
And I'm using this code from jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){  
 
// All variables needed in functions  
var menuSection = $('.fullwidth-menu');
var hamburgerIcon = $('.fullwidth-open');
var menuLink = $('.fullwidth-menu a');
var subMenu = $('.main-menu-item ul');
var toggleIcon = $('.toggle-sub-menu');
   
   
// Open fullwidth menu & animate items  
hamburgerIcon.click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    menuSection.toggleClass('fullwidth-menu-open');
    if (menuSection.hasClass("fullwidth-menu-open")) {
        anime({
        targets: '.stagger-effect',
        translateY: [150, 0],
        opacity: [0, 1],
        loop: false,
        delay: anime.stagger(100, {easing: 'easeOutQuad'})
        });
 
    } else { 
        subMenu.slideUp();  
        toggleIcon.text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+'); 
    }
});
 
// Close fullwidth menu when clicking an item
menuLink.click(function(){
    hamburgerIcon.toggleClass('open');
    menuSection.toggleClass('fullwidth-menu-open');  
  subMenu.slideUp();  
        toggleIcon.text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
});
   
// Change icon when toggling the submenu  
toggleIcon.click(function(){  
    var subMenu = $(this).parent().find("ul");
    subMenu.slideToggle(); 
    $(this).text($(this).text() == '-' ? '+' : '-');
});
```

I want to make sure when I clicked in the ToggleIcon It closes the other ones open!
Can you help me please?

Comment: what issue is coming?

Comment: you can also use bootstrap library

Comment: The ```jQuery``` code you posted, is this what you tried, or did you just copy it from somewhere?

Comment: Consider editing your question to describe the problem that you want to correct. Also consider editing your last sentence to ask a specific question about that problem instead of "Can you help me please?".